# Excel open option missing from Context Menu

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, windows-explorer, microsoft-excel-2010, context-menu

Whenever I select multiple Excel (2010) files the right mouseclick option 'open' disappears. When I select just one or a few files there is no problem, but from 15 or more files I can't open them at once anymore.

In the picture you'll see there is no 'open' option. Usually this option is above 7-Zip along with 'New' and 'Print'

[image: excel open option missing]

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can change this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you repeat this behaviour with Word? I suspect this is to prevent opening too many files accidentally. What happens when you Shift-Right-click?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows removes certain options from the context menu when more than 15 items are selected. According to [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2022295), that's by design, to prevent accidentally performing those actions on a large number of files.

You can, however, change that limit in the registry. From that same KB article:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
Name : MultipleInvokePromptMinimum
Type : DWORD
Default : 15 (decimal)
```

Setting the value to 16 or higher effectively removes the limit.